# YAML / ruamel output formatting. Are there any other knobs?

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have the following python string dictionary and am using ruamel to dump it out as yaml file.

```
    import sys
    import json
    import ruamel.yaml


    dit = "'{p_d: '{a:3, what:3.6864e-05, s:lion, vec_mode:'{2.5, -2.9, 3.4, 5.6, -8.9, -5.67, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5.4, 2, 2, 6.545, 2, 2}, sst:'{c:-20, b:6, p:panther}}}"


    yaml_str = dit.replace('"', '').replace("'",'').replace(':', ': ').replace('{','[').replace('}',']')
    print(yaml_str)

    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe') # 
    yaml.default_flow_style = False
    yaml.allow_duplicate_keys = True
    data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
    print("data: {}".format(data))

    fileo = open("yamloutput.yaml", "w")
    yaml.dump(data, fileo)
    fileo.close()
```

The output it prints as:

```
    - p_d:
      - a: 3
      - what: 3.6864e-05
      - s: lion
      - vec_mode:
        - 2.5
        - -2.9
        - 3.4
        - 5.6
        - -8.9
        - -5.67
        - 2
        - 2
        - 2
        - 2
        - 5.4
        - 2
        - 2
        - 6.545
        - 2
        - 2
      - sst:
        - c: -20
        - b: 6
        - p: panther
```

but the expected / desired output is as follows:

```
    p_d:
      a: 3
      what: 3.6864e-05
      s: lion
      vec_mode:
        - 2.5
        - -2.9
        - 3.4
        - 5.6
        - -8.9
        - -5.67
        - 2
        - 2
        - 2
        - 2
        - 5.4
        - 2
        - 2
        - 6.545
        - 2
        - 2
      sst:
        c: -20
        b: 6
        p: panther
```

Is there any formatting that can be done/configured in ruamel to get this desired output i.e. instead of underscore use the proper tabs, and for the arrays alone use the underscores as represented?

**Update to the Query:**
In the above query, in the dit string when I tried adding two sub strings like given below.

```
dit="'{p_d: '{a:3, what:3.6864e-05, s:lion, vec_mode:'{2.5, 1e9, -2.9, 3.4, 5.6, -8.9, -5.67, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5.4, 2, 2, 6.545, 2, 2}, sst:'{c:-20, b:6, p:panther}}}\n'{mgbp: '{ifftp:'{ipdp:'{ipdncf:'{rand_type:no, mfn:\"bbbb.txt\", rng_speed:-967901775, np:-1187634210}}}}}"
```

Getting the following error:

`"ruamel.yaml.parser.ParserError: did not find expected <document start>"`

I tried adding ---\n to the beginning of the string but still got the same error.

Any suggestions or comments ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You convert the argument for the root level and for the root level key `p_d` into a list with your string replacement. So the
output is exactly what you should expect to get in `yamloutput.yaml`.

If that is what you want without affecting the value for key `vec_mode` you either have to do more specific
parsing, or clean up after loading:

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

path = Path('yamloutput.yaml')

dit = "'{p_d: '{a:3, what:3.6864e-05, s:lion, vec_mode:'{2.5, -2.9, 3.4, 5.6, -8.9, -5.67, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5.4, 2, 2, 6.545, 2, 2}, sst:'{c:-20, b:6, p:panther}}}"


yaml_str = dit.replace('"', '').replace("'",'').replace(':', ': ').replace('{','[').replace('}',']')

def cleanup(d):
    if isinstance(d, list):
        ret_val = {}
        for elem in d:
            assert len(elem) == 1 and isinstance(elem, dict)
            ret_val.update(elem)
        return ret_val
    return d
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
yaml.default_flow_style = False
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
data = cleanup(data)
data['p_d'] = cleanup(data['p_d'])
data['p_d']['sst'] = cleanup(data['p_d']['sst'])

yaml.dump(data, path)

sys.stdout.write(path.read_text())
```

which gives:

```
p_d:
  a: 3
  s: lion
  sst:
    b: 6
    c: -20
    p: panther
  vec_mode:
  - 2.5
  - -2.9
  - 3.4
  - 5.6
  - -8.9
  - -5.67
  - 2
  - 2
  - 2
  - 2
  - 5.4
  - 2
  - 2
  - 6.545
  - 2
  - 2
  what: 3.6864e-05
```

If all lists consisting of a single element dict should be converted you can make `cleanup` call itself recursively.

If the key ordering is important to you, you should not use `typ='safe'` and then (recursively) set the flow-style on the collection nodes to block-style.

Comment: Hello Anthon, I faced a new error when tried adding couple of strings onto the same string.

Comment: Post a new question, tag it `ruamel.yaml` and I'll get notified.